# Error al querer mostrar datos en Vue js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Soy novato en vue js y estoy tratando de pintar los datos obtenidos de la API de marvel, los cuales los traigo con un async y await, luego los guardo en un array vacio en la data(), los puedo mostrar en consola sin problema pero a la hora de pintarlos por pantalla con un v-for no me los muestra me salta este error en la consola que debe ser??

HTML

```
<div id="app">
   <ul>
       <li v-for="(heroes, index) in hero" :key="index"></li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

APP.js

```
var app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    heroes: [],
  },
  methods: {
    async callAPI() {
      try {
        const url = await fetch(
          `https://gateway.marvel.com:443/v1/public/characters?ts=1&apikey=cb33c54f61cb0d01030a55f03e55d180&hash=e96601cf957b02f0b5c1939c1dba3ac6`
        );
        const res = await url.json();
        const heroes = res.data.results;
        heroes.forEach((hero) => {
          this.heroes.push(hero);
        });
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    },
  },
  created() {
    this.callAPI();
  },
});
```

Error:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El código va como texto

Comment: Nada del otro mundo, solo tienes al revés los valores del for in, debe ser así: `(hero, index) in heroes`

Comment: Muchas gracias!! Saludos

Comment: Si gustas tu mismo responde tu pregunta y cuando el sistema te deje la marcas como aceptada así los demás nos enteramos de la solución